# Using getBoundingClientRect() when resizing the window

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this navbar and everytime I click an option in the navbar the absolute positioned indicator gets the position of the option on the left and the width with the help of `getBoundingClientRect()` and it is moved to the target.

The problem is when I resize the window the indicator changes it's position and moves away.To stay in the same place when I resize the window I applied an eventListener to the window and everytime is resized I get the new values of `left` and `width` with `getBoundingClientRect()`.

It works but I wonder if that is a bad way to do it because of the calculations that happen everytime the window is resized and if that is the case what is a better way to do this.

Here is the code:

```js
const navigator = document.querySelector('.navigator');
const firstOption = document.querySelector('.first-option');
const navOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-option');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

navigator.style.left = `${firstOption.getBoundingClientRect().left}px`;
navigator.style.width = `${firstOption.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;

nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('nav-option')) {
    navOptions.forEach(option => option.classList.remove('nav-option-active'));
    e.target.classList.add('nav-option-active');

    navigator.style.left = `${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().left}px`;
    navigator.style.width = `${e.target.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;
  };
});

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  let navOptionActive = nav.querySelector('.nav-option-active');

  navigator.style.left = `${navOptionActive.getBoundingClientRect().left}px`;
  navigator.style.width = `${navOptionActive.getBoundingClientRect().width}px`;
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav {
 position: relative;
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 100px auto;
 padding: 7vh 30vw;
 width: auto;
 background:#eeeeee;
}

.nav-option {
  padding: 0 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: orangered;
  transition: .4s ease all;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-option {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div class="navigator"></div>
  <div class="nav-option first-option nav-option-active">HOME</div>
  <div class="nav-option">INFO</div>
  <div class="nav-option">CONTACT</div>
  <div class="nav-option">ABOUT</div>
  <div class="nav-option">MENU</div>
</nav>
```

Comment: If you don't want to do all that work (calculations) in your script, you can consider having a `navigator` under each `nav-option` and show/hide them selectively based on active `nav-option`.

Answer (score 2):

If you have to use `getBoundingClientRect` (which honestly has nothing wrong with it), you can throttle the call, so that only the last resize after sufficient time has passed will execute. There are zillion ways of doing this, I will leave one example:

```js
window.onresize = (function(id = null, delay = 600, oEvent = null){
    return function fire(event){
        return (new Promise(function(res,rej){
            if (id !== null){
                oEvent = event;
                rej("busy");
                return;
            }
            id = setTimeout(function(){
                res(oEvent || event);
            },delay);
        })).then(function(event){
            id = null;
            console.log(event, "do getBoundingClientRect call");
        }).catch(function(){void(0);});
    };
}());
```

Replace `console.log` with what you want to do.

Your other option is to switch to [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API), if you can restructure your rendering logic. That will require some work

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `<nav>` element tightly wrap the buttons, then position the underline relative to the `<nav>`. A new wrapper `<div>` around the `<nav>` takes care of the margins and gray background. Instead of `getBoundingClientRect()` you then need to use `offsetLeft` and `offsetWidth`.

Note that this doesn't handle the changes in response to your `@media` query. For that, you could add a `resize` listener that specifically only handles changes across the 1200px threshold. Alternatively, you could reparent the underline to be a child of the actual nav button while it's not animating. Neither solution is great, but both would get the job done.

```js
const navigator = document.querySelector('.navigator');
const firstOption = document.querySelector('.first-option');
const navOptions = document.querySelectorAll('.nav-option');
const nav = document.querySelector('nav');

navigator.style.left = `${firstOption.offsetLeft}px`;
navigator.style.width = `${firstOption.offsetWidth}px`;

nav.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if(e.target.classList.contains('nav-option')) {
    navOptions.forEach(option => option.classList.remove('nav-option-active'));
    e.target.classList.add('nav-option-active');

    navigator.style.left = `${e.target.offsetLeft}px`;
    navigator.style.width = `${e.target.offsetWidth}px`;
  };
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.nav-wrapper {
  margin: 100px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  background: #eeeeee;
}

nav {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
}

.nav-option {
  padding: 7vh 15px;
  font-size: 22px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.navigator {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 5px;
  background: orangered;
  transition: .4s ease all;
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) {
  .nav-option {
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
  <nav>
    <div class="navigator"></div>
    <div class="nav-option first-option nav-option-active">HOME</div>
    <div class="nav-option">INFO</div>
    <div class="nav-option">CONTACT</div>
    <div class="nav-option">ABOUT</div>
    <div class="nav-option">MENU</div>
  </nav>
</div>
```